# Android development - Status Bar not showing on pre Lollipop (AppCompat)

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, statusbar, android-appcompat, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm developing my app using appcompat v21.0.3 and testing on API 21 android ver 5.0.1.Today I decided to test the application on the tablet with Android 4.4.2, and everything would be ok but I did notice that the status bar has become transparent and dropped to toolbar. I have attached pictures and i hope for your help.
P.S
Sorry for my english, i used google translator to make this text :)

It looks like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4Sve.png
But should look like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR1B7.jpg

Comment: please share some code ?

Comment: exactly what code? Activity? layout or style.xml?

Comment: share your manifest for start ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ZD3g2xgX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your manfest replace

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

with

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

Use the below code the your Main Activity to assign color to status bar.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = this.getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.main_red_dark));
        }
```

Of course, this is just one way. I am not 100% sure, where your are actually changing the code of status bar. It has to be done.

Comment: O Thanks a lot! It worked, but how customize theme now? I prefer to add colorControlNormar and other items.  Only from code?

Comment: As I said, this is just one of the ways! there was something else wrong earlier. If you can share your style.xml I can help you getting the status bar colored from your last code. Without using this one!

Comment: style.xml - http://pastebin.com/g5qKPMrM style.xml(v21) - http://pastebin.com/NBXrFemt

Comment: try to use 
<item name="android:colorPrimary">#005555</item>
<item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#003333</item>
it should do the trick

Comment: replace hex colors with your colors !

Comment: Is that new solution or addtional for above?

Comment: Nope( It's very strange because i used same styles and code in my previous app and its worked good. One thing from that moment i change is updating appcompat lib.

Comment: I think you have missed "android:" name space in item names ? Is that the bug ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your app style.xml.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
     <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primarycolor</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@color/Textcolor</item>


</style>
```

Comment: I already have Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar parent, i tryed to change to DarkActionBar but nothing change.

Comment: This is the part you need to change!

Comment: Ok, @color/Text what is this? Text?